# How to ensure that when my process is operating on a file, no other process tries to write to it or delete it?

Tags: c, file, file-locking

If my process is trying to read from a file, then how do I ensure from my code (C Language) that no other process either writes to it or deletes it (include system commands for deleting the file)?

Also, can this be achieved on all OS (Windows, Linux, Solaris, HP-UX, VxWorks etc)?

Comment: As far as I know it's going to be completely dependent on the OS, but I've been out-of-the-loop in C for 15 years.

Comment: Oh and if you're googling for answers the terminology is "file locking".

Comment: Nitpicking technicality: you don't care whether another process tries to write to it or tries to delete it - you only care that the other process does not succeed.  You really can't stop processes trying.  You might be able to stop them succeeding.

Comment: @Jonathan, Yes. I meant the same thing, I don't another process to succeed.

Comment: [What problem are you solving?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/54262)

Comment: @Roger, In my code, I try to read from a file, I am worried someone (a person manually or another process) may delete it or write to it. How do I protect the file I am operating on?

Comment: Why are you worried it may be deleted or written to?  Sorry, but you just restated the original attempted solution without any more information.

Comment: Also, what would you do if the file just disappears? E.g. it was on a USB stick and somebody just pulled that out. You may stop system commands, but stopping people is harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit: I'll answer for Unix/Linux*

As gspr and others said, take a look at file locking using `fcntl`, `flock`, etc. However, be warned that those are **ADVISORY LOCKING** methods.

What does this mean? It means you can warn other processes that you are currently accesing a file, or a portion of it, but **you can't forcibly keep them from ignoring you and writing all over your file**.

There are no COMPULSORY locking primitives. You can use permissions to your advantage, but you'll never have full guarantees -- the root user can always override your limitations. I don't think there's a way to work around that.

Answer (score 1):

For POSIX systems, take a look at `fcntl`. `flock` could also be of interest, although I don't think it's a part of POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the file with READ sharing permissions, which means anyone else trying to open it can only get read access. As @Pointy says, this is OS specific and you'll probably have to code this separately for Windows, Linux, etc. However, most modern OSs *should* support this.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file, make your changes, then rename it back over the original.

Another method, if the file doesn't yet exist, is to create the file using exclusive flags, then delete it from the filesystem. Perform your writing, then hard link it back into the filesystem (it presently exists only as an open inode). You can make use of `/proc` for the source path.

Comment: On Linux, `O_TMPFILE` can be used to avoid cluttering the filesystem if you crash unexpectedly, but still allow it to be `linkat`ed back into the filesystem.